# Magento 2:Change Admin Form label

Tags: magento-2.1, customer, adminform

I want to change the text "Zip/Postal Code" in customer admin form to "PIN Code". Where is the file location to make this change? I have enabled admin path hints. Is it possible to change the text using translation file.

Please help..

Comment: Only for backend or frontend?

Comment: only for backend